# Angular-flexSlider start at specific slide using value from the scope not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, flexslider

I'm using angular-flexslider and i specified the start slide using value from the scope. But it doesn't work. startAt take currentSlide as value not 5.

```
$scope.currentSlide=5;

<flex-slider slide="slide in slides track by $index" start-at="currentSlide">
            <li>
                <img ng-src="{{slide}}">
            </li>
```

Does any one know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like angular-flexslider expects an integer, not an expression: https://github.com/thenikso/angular-flexslider

startAt: 0,                     //Integer: The slide that the slider should start on. Array notation (0 = first slide)

Try:

```
$scope.currentSlide = 5;

<flex-slider slide="slide in slides track by $index" start-at="{{ currentSlide }}">
    <li>
        <img ng-src="{{slide}}">
    </li>
</flex-slider>
```

Comment: yes when i specify a number it works. but i want to set it dynamically.